# Is there a way to override an app delegate in a framework in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm currently developing a framework in Swift and I have to check if the 
app has been opened through a url scheme.
To do so I add this into my appdelegate file when developing an app :

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    print("went back")
    return true
}
```

The thing is that UIApplication cannot be imported in a framework.
Is there a way to catch that event without having to do it in the app ?

Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal way to do that. For example there is no iOS default notification which is posted in this case and can be observed.

I see 2 ways of implementing it:

1) Redirect method call (Probably as you did). [VK SDK](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk) implemented redirection this way.

For example:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
    {
        let result = MySDK.sharedInstance().openURL(url, options: options)
        reutrn result
    }
```

Pros: Explicit, developers will know where your SDK handles "open url".

Cons: You need developers to know that they need to add this line of code

2) Create Base App Delegate ([Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) uses this approach). So you create base class which implements this method and force developers to use it as a super class of their `AppDelegate`

```
class BaseAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool
        {
            let result = MySDK.sharedInstance().openURL(url, options: options)
            reutrn result
        }
}

class MyAppDelegate: BaseAppDelegate {

 // Implement some custom app delegate

}
```

Pros: Easier to implement by developers.

Cons: Not so explicit as previous approach, if this method will be overriden by `MyAppDelegate`, super needs to be called.